# Impala query paging with Spark JdbcRDD

Tags: jdbc, apache-spark, rdd, impala

I'm trying to turn the output of an impala query into a Spark RDD (or dataframe).  The documentation for JdbcRDD can be found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/JdbcRDD.html).  Connecting and querying impala through the JDBC driver from cloudera works just fine.  The problem is that JdbcRDD needs upper and lower bounds as well as a [PreparedStatement](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/preparedstatement.html) sql statement that pages.

I can't seem to get paging PreparedStatements to work when querying impala.  What is the syntax for this?  I can't find Impala docs for it.

I'm trying to avoid collecting the entire resultset on the spark driver, that's why I'm moving from this logic (which works perfectly):

```
val resultSetList = Iterator.continually((rs.next(), rs)).takeWhile(_._1).map(r => {
   getRowFromResultSet(r._2)  // (ResultSet) => (spark.sql.Row)
}).toList
sc.parallelize(resultSetList)
```

to using the JdbcRDD which will automatically parallelize the data and distribute it across the cluster.